# Spring Integration JMS header 'priority' must be a number

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, activemq-classic, gateway

I'm using Spring Integration JMS 5.1.3 with ActiveMQ, and I found an error with mapping priority:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'priority' header value must be a Number.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.verifyType(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.java:177) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor.setHeader(MessageHeaderAccessor.java:305) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor.lambda$copyHeaders$0(MessageHeaderAccessor.java:396) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor.copyHeaders(MessageHeaderAccessor.java:394) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.copyHeaders(MessageBuilder.java:179) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.copyHeaders(MessageBuilder.java:48) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:327) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736) ~[spring-jms-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696) ~[spring-jms-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) ~[spring-jms-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318) [spring-jms-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257) [spring-jms-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189) [spring-jms-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179) [spring-jms-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076) [spring-jms-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

My message header as following:

[image]

I have disabled the inbound message header for Priority:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsHeaderMapper jmsHeaderMapper() {
    final DefaultJmsHeaderMapper mapper = new DefaultJmsHeaderMapper();
    {
        mapper.setMapInboundDeliveryMode(true);
        mapper.setMapInboundExpiration(true);
        mapper.setMapInboundPriority(false);
    }
    return mapper;
}
```

Is there any resolution for this issue ?

The inbound message in DEBUG log:

```
2019-03-01 09:51:51.278 DEBUG 4224 --- [sage-listener-1] .i.j.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener : converted JMS Message [ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 19, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:hot-srv-wso2-01-44620-1551368625113-1:4:3:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:hot-srv-wso2-01-44620-1551368625113-1:4:3:1, destination = queue://extraction-request, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1551408495720, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1551408705168, brokerOutTime = 1551408705172, correlationId = ID:hot-srv-wso2-01-44620-1551368625113-1:3:3:1:1, replyTo = queue://extraction-response, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@67153d1f, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 6, size = 0, properties = {Connection=Keep-Alive, User-Agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5), Host=10.10.15.235:8280, Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate, jms_type=vn.sps.ias.domain.Response, priority=4, JMS_DESTINATION=ReqOutput, JMS_REPLY_TO=ReqROutput, Content-Length=38, JMS_REDELIVERED=false, Content-Type=application/json, timestamp=1551408705049}, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = {"text":"1 was processed"}}] to integration Message payload []
```

Comment: What JMS client & broker are you using? Can you provide the full stack-trace from Spring?

Comment: Please find my update for full stack trace of the error. The broker is ActiveMQ

Comment: May we have some small project from you somewhere on GitHub to play with? I don't see how it cannot be a `Number` when you still use ` mapper.setMapInboundPriority(true);`...

Comment: You can take a look at the message Properties from the image, @Artem Bilan, there is "priority". In my case, from the JMS producer, i remove this property, and it works.

Comment: I see those properties and headers, but that doesn't prove how it can be not an `Integer`. You might use some custom `headerMapper` wherre you map `priority` into string. That's why some project from you would be great to have for playing.

Comment: I have uploaded the code now at [link](https://github.com/wisekingtran/regex-extractor)

Comment: The project is too big and there is a lot of custom code which we would need to understand first of all. Also there is no instruction how to reproduce an issue. Any chances to minimize it as much as possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me, this problem occurred when I used the header "priority" in a custom message.

```
 MessageBuilder.withPayload(val).setHeader("priority", true).build();
```

It seems as "priority" is a header value you must not use.

Changing to

```
 MessageBuilder.withPayload(val).setHeader("prio", true).build();
```

solved the problem for me.